# VB Microwave oven wrong display

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

i'm creating a microwave oven app for class. I have the majority of the app working great, the only problem is i'm getting a weird display output, I believe it has to do with my sub string format, but i'm not entirely sure. Basically whats happening is that if the user were to enter say 1:25 cook time, the output reads 1:125 and if start is hit, the microwave only counts down from 1:00. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Private Sub DisplayTime()
  Dim hour As Integer
  Dim second As Integer
  Dim minute As Integer

  Dim display As String ' String displays current input

  ' if too much input entered
    If timeIs.Length > 5 Then
        timeIs = timeIs.Substring(0, 5)
    End If

    display = timeIs.PadLeft(5, "0"c)

    ' extract seconds, minutes, and hours
    second = Convert.ToInt32(display.Substring(2))
    minute = Convert.ToInt32(display.Substring(1, 2))
    hour = Convert.ToInt32(display.Substring(0, 1))

    ' display number of hours, minutes, ":" seconds
    displayLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D1}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
    hour, minute, second)
 End Sub ' DisplayTime

' event handler displays new time each second
Private Sub clockTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object,
  e As System.EventArgs) Handles clockTimer.Tick

  ' perform countdown, subtract one second
  If timeObject.Second > 0 Then
     timeObject.Second -= 1
        displayLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D1}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        timeObject.Hour, timeObject.Minute, timeObject.Second)
  ElseIf timeObject.Minute > 0 Then
     timeObject.Minute -= 1
     timeObject.Second = 59
        displayLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D1}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        timeObject.Hour, timeObject.Minute, timeObject.Second)

    ElseIf timeObject.Hour > 0 Then
        timeObject.Hour -= 1
        timeObject.Minute = 59
        timeObject.Second = 59
        displayLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D1}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        timeObject.Hour, timeObject.Minute, timeObject.Second)
    Else ' countdown finished
        clockTimer.Enabled = False ' stop timer
        Beep()
        displayLabel.Text = "Done!" ' inform user time is finished
        windowPanel.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
    End If
End Sub ' clockTimer_Tick
End Class ' MicrowaveOvenForm
```

Comment: What if `timeIs` has "99999" in it?  That would pass your Convert.ToInt32() calls, but should that be considered a valid time?

Answer (score 3):

You Substring() for extracting the seconds portion is wrong.

Change:

```
second = Convert.ToInt32(display.Substring(2))
```

To:

```
second = Convert.ToInt32(display.Substring(3, 2))
```

*Are you required to use "timeObject" though?  There are much better ways of keeping a countdown...

Comment: Yes, we were required to use it by our instructor. And thank you for the fix, everything is working now! :)

Comment: Awesome.  Hit that checkmark so others know the problem is solved.